# SOAP in iOS Application

Tags: ios, xml, parsing, soap, wsdl

I'm trying to develop an app that uses data from a SOAP service. is the first time I use a SOAP service. After reading several tutorials I thought I would be able to set the request to the service in the right way but I always get errors in the response. What's wrong ?!

```
NSString *soapMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n"
                 "<env:Envelope xmlns:env=\"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope\" xmlns:ns1=\"urn:Lottery.Intf-ILottery\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:enc=\"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding\">\n"
                 "<env:Body>\n"
                 "<ns1:GetUpcomingLotteries env:encodingStyle=\"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding\">\n"
                 "<EntityID xsi:type=\"xsd:int\">2</EntityID>\n"
                 "<Password xsi:type=\"xsd:string\">Smart@Winners</Password>\n"
                 "<SortBy xsi:type=\"xsd:int\">0</SortBy>\n"
                 "<limit xsi:type=\"xsd:int\">0</limit>\n"
                 "</ns1:GetUpcomingLotteries>\n"
                 "</env:Body>\n"
                 "</env:Envelope>"];


NSURL *sRequestURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"xxxxxxxxx"];
NSMutableURLRequest *myRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:sRequestURL];
NSString *sMessageLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [soapMessage length]];

[myRequest addValue: @"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[myRequest addValue: @"urn:Lottery.Intf-ILottery/GetUpcomingLotteries" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
[myRequest addValue: sMessageLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

[myRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[myRequest setHTTPBody: [soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSError *error;
NSURLResponse *response;
NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:myRequest returningResponse:&response error:&error];
NSString *str=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: what kind of error ?

Comment: @iphonemaclover no get data...

Comment: means your soap envelop is invalid. Try SOA client to test your API and get your envelope over there and then test

Comment: @iphonemaclover do have any sample code or link ??

Comment: load TBXML files from github for parser xml

Comment: Hello Mr. iphonemaclover do you chek url : http://isapi.mekashron.com/soapclient/soapclient.php?URL=http://isapi.mekashron.com/SmartWinners/LotteryWS.dll%2Fwsdl%2FILottery

Comment: No yar same issue :(

Comment: working fine in php side

Comment: ok i will check it tomorrow running my end...good day

Comment: i get this response
{"methods":[],"types":[],"native":["int","integer","double","string","date","datetime","bool","boolean","float","decimal"]}

Is it meaning ful ?
let me upload sample code in github

Comment: check https://github.com/dsrawat4u/SOAPstackoverflow

Answer (score 1):

DOWNLOAD [ATTACHED PROJECT HERE](http://github.com/dsrawat4u/SOAPstackoverflow)
**// in .h file**

```
#import "TBXML.h"

@property(retain,nonatomic)NSString *xmlString;

@property(nonatomic,retain)NSMutableData *webResponseData;
```

**// in .m file**

```
-(void)method_GetUpcomingLotteries
{



    NSString *soapMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n"
                             "<env:Envelope xmlns:env=\"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope\" xmlns:ns1=\"urn:Lottery.Intf-ILottery\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:enc=\"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding\">\n"
                             "<env:Body>\n"
                             "<ns1:GetUpcomingLotteries env:encodingStyle=\"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding\">\n"
                             "<EntityID xsi:type=\"xsd:int\">2</EntityID>\n"
                             "<Password xsi:type=\"xsd:string\">Smart@Winners</Password>\n"
                             "<SortBy xsi:type=\"xsd:int\">0</SortBy>\n"
                             "<limit xsi:type=\"xsd:int\">0</limit>\n"
                             "</ns1:GetUpcomingLotteries>\n"
                             "</env:Body>\n"
                             "</env:Envelope>"];


    NSURL *sRequestURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"xxxxxxxxx"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:sRequestURL];
    NSString *sMessageLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [soapMessage length]];

    [request addValue: @"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request addValue: @"urn:Lottery.Intf-ILottery/GetUpcomingLotteries" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
    [request addValue: sMessageLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];



    [request setHTTPBody:[soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    NSLog(@"soapMessage===\n %@",soapMessage);

    NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    if( theConnection ) {
        NSLog(@"hiii");
        [self showUpdating];
        self.webResponseData = [NSMutableData data];
    }else {
        NSLog(@"Some error occurred in Connection");

        [self showNetworkError];
    }

}


- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSLog(@"Received Bytes from server: %lu", (unsigned long)[self.webResponseData length]);

    NSString * strXml = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes: [self.webResponseData mutableBytes] length:[self.webResponseData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"---- %@" ,strXml);

    TBXML *sourceXML = [[TBXML alloc] initWithXMLString:strXml error:nil];
    TBXMLElement *rootElement = sourceXML.rootXMLElement;
    TBXMLElement *entryElement = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"soap:Body" parentElement:rootElement];




}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {

               [self.webResponseData  setLength:0];
           }

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
               [self.webResponseData  appendData:data];
    }

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
               NSLog(@"Some error in your Connection. Please try again.");

               [self showNetworkError];

           }
```

Or Open FireFox
Install SOA Client Extension
Test Your API over there

[image]

[image]

Updates On check in SOA Client i get following header

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Body><GetUpcomingLotteries xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"><EntityID>2</EntityID><Password>Smart@Winners</Password><SortBy>0</SortBy><limit>0</limit></GetUpcomingLotteries></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

**And following response (MEANS ITS A SERVER ERROR MIGHT BE)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
<title>500 - Internal server error.</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
body{margin:0;font-size:.7em;font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;background:#EEEEEE;}
fieldset{padding:0 15px 10px 15px;} 
h1{font-size:2.4em;margin:0;color:#FFF;}
h2{font-size:1.7em;margin:0;color:#CC0000;} 
h3{font-size:1.2em;margin:10px 0 0 0;color:#000000;} 
#header{width:96%;margin:0 0 0 0;padding:6px 2% 6px 2%;font-family:"trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;color:#FFF;
background-color:#555555;}
#content{margin:0 0 0 2%;position:relative;}
.content-container{background:#FFF;width:96%;margin-top:8px;padding:10px;position:relative;}
-->
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header"><h1>Server Error</h1></div>
<div id="content">
 <div class="content-container"><fieldset>
  <h2>500 - Internal server error.</h2>
  <h3>There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.</h3>
 </fieldset></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: NSURL *sRequestURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"xxxxxxxxx"]; 
add your base url over here!

Comment: my url is : http://isapi.mekashron.com/SmartWinners/LotteryWS.dll/wsdl/ILottery

and SoapAction is : GetUpcomingLotteries

Comment: http://isapi.mekashron.com/SmartWinners/LotteryWS.dll/wsdl/ILottery able to run in soap client...provide me parameter

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:ns1="urn:Lottery.Intf-ILottery" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:enc="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding"><env:Body><ns1:GetUpcomingLotteries env:encodingStyle="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding"><EntityID xsi:type="xsd:int">2</EntityID><Password xsi:type="xsd:string">Smart@Winners</Password><SortBy xsi:type="xsd:int">0</SortBy><limit xsi:type="xsd:int">0</limit></ns1:GetUpcomingLotteries>

Comment: </env:Body></env:Envelope>

Comment: METHOD : GetUpcomingLotteries

Comment: check edit answer,its server side API issue in my point of view,please check

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80559/discussion-between-iphonemaclover-and-bhavesh-nai).

Comment: Hello iPhonemaclover check this url : http://isapi.mekashron.com/soapclient/soapclient.php?URL=http://isapi.mekashron.com/SmartWinners/LotteryWS.dll%2Fwsdl%2FILottery

Comment: select : GetUpcomingLotteries

Comment: enter value : EntityID : 2 Password : Smart@Winners

Comment: we got data in this url :(